# Laravel 8 Form Submit does not submit, unexpected behavior occurs

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-8

I am trying to create a form submit but I bumped to a unexpected scenario.

- When form submitted by clicking the submit button
- The web app reroute to my `index` page of the `resource route`
- With the form variable and values appended in the URL.

**Example**

URL before submitting: http://127.0.0.1/admin/products/create

URL after submitted: http://127.0.0.1/admin/products?_token=qQ4klvK2egdsP77iMY4RQhXd5laJDUONRyuh8oQd&productTitle=&productPrice=

**View (create.blade.php)**

```
<form type="POST" name="productAddForm" action="{{ route('products.store')  }}" >
    @csrf
    <div class="mb-3 col-5">
         <label for="productTitle" class="form-label">Title</label>
         <input name="productTitle" type="text" class="form-control" id="productTitle">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 col-5">
         <label for="productPrice" class="form-label">Price</label>
         <input name="productPrice" type="number" class="form-control" id="productPrice">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

**Controller (ProductController.php)**

```
public function create()
{
    return view('layouts/admin/product.create');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

**Route (web.php)**

```
Route::resource('admin/products', ProductController::class)->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL parameters in your second link are a giveaway that your form data is being serialized as a `GET` request instead of submitted as a `POST` request.

There is no `<form>` `type=` attribute. You need to use `method=`.

```php
<form method="POST" ...
```

Comment: How I missed that `type` instead of `method`. You have a keen eye for details. Thanks you save me an hours